# Why is date displayed differently on different PC?

Tags: java, html, date, jpa

I have a strange problem with a filed of date type. It's an application developed with spring and JPA. I have a very simple input filed of type date

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <label>Start Date</label> 
        <input type="date" class="form-control needs-validation" name="startDate"
        value="${selected}">
</div>
```

Nothing special here.
The problem appears on I try this app on different pc (same browser, same version of browser, same operating system).

On one pc the format of date is :

[image]

If I try the same page on other pc the output is:

[image]

I don't understand why I have a different date format using same version of code/browser/os. At the end, the inserted date is received correct but this is very annoying and is not a very user-friendly format to have the day in middle of the date.

Can somebody give me some hints about this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The second one is standard in the US, is it possible a location/timezone setting could mess with it?

Comment: Hi @Nexevis. No, it is not based on the windows timezone. For example, for the second image, the format is dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: As per input type="date" specifications, the standard format is yyyy-mm-dd, however the display is upto the browser's locale as well. Could you please check on the browser locale settings in both the browsers ?

Specifications reference here - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339

Comment: @SB the only settings that could refer to timezone from the browser is Language and both are set to English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Browser behavior varies

The HTML widget `input` of type `date` displays a date value as it sees fit, with behavior varying between web browser implementations.  To quote the [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> The input UI generally varies from browser to browser; see [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility) for further details. In unsupported browsers, the control degrades gracefully to `<input type="text">`.

I expect that behavior within a browser varies by the user’s preference settings for date-time, current default time zone, and current default locale.

So this has **nothing to do with Java** or your database.

If you want more control, you will need to use other HTML widgets.

On the Java side, I suggest you learn about the *java.time* classes. They have been covered many many times, so search to learn more. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

If you want to build your web app entirely in Java while all the HTML, CSS, JavaScript, AJAX, DOM, etc. is automatically generated, learn about [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com]).

Comment: Yes, from what I have read in doc this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your browsers have different language settings. Check the settings of each browser and set them to the same language.

Comment: Hi. Good idea but that is not the problem. I have English for both browsers

Comment: There are different types of "english". English UK, US, Australia, ....? I think they might also have different date format.

Comment: Yes, I also was thinking about that and I have added on both browsers just English, without any "particular" english